# OpenCV compile Eigenface.cpp in Linux with using CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I want to compile the following OpenCV programm with CodeBlocks or with Linux Terminal.

http://plaza.ufl.edu/tyler727/imdl/src/eigenface.cpp

```
    line 57:   nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("/home/hacker/data/Eigenfacecpp/train.txt");

    line 192: // load test images and ground truth for person number
             nTestFaces = loadFaceImgArray("/home/hacker/data/Eigenfacecpp/test.txt");

    // project the training images onto the PCA subspace
    projectedTrainFaceMat = cvCreateMat(nTrainFaces, nEigens, CV_32FC1);
    for(i=0; i<nTrainFaces; i++)
    {
        cvEigenDecomposite(faceImgArr[i],
                           nEigens,
                           eigenVectArr,
                           0, 0,
                           pAvgTrainImg,
line 78:                    projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*nEigens);
    }

     cvCalcEigenObjects(nTrainFaces,
                        (void*)faceImgArr,
                        (void*)eigenVectArr,
                        CV_EIGOBJ_NO_CALLBACK,
                        0,
                        0,
                        &calcLimit,
                        pAvgTrainImg,
line 154:                eigenValMat->data.fl);

        //project the test image onto the PCA subspace
        cvEigenDecomposite(faceImgArr[i],
                           nEigens,
                           eigenVectArr,
                           0, 0,
                           pAvgTrainImg,
line 211:                   projectedTestFace);
```

And i got those errors:

```
Compiling: eigenface.cpp

In Function »void learn()«:
line 57:  deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [Wwrite-strings]

In Function »double recognize()«:
line 192: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [Wwrite-strings]

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
obj/Debug/eigenface.o: In function `learn()':
/home/hacker/data/Eigenfacecpp/eigenface.cpp:78: undefined reference to `cvEigenDecomposite'

obj/Debug/eigenface.o: In function `doPCA()':
/home/hacker/data/Eigenfacecpp/eigenface.cpp:154: undefined reference to `cvCalcEigenObjects'

obj/Debug/eigenface.o: In function `recognize()':
/home/hacker/data/Eigenfacecpp/eigenface.cpp:211: undefined reference to `cvEigenDecomposite'
```

I don't understand what I did wrong. I think it's something stupid but I can't find it.

Compiler and Debugger Settings from CodeBlocks:

Linker Settings->Other Options: `-lopencv_core -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_imgproc` -lopencv_highgui

Search Directories->Compiler: `/usr/local/include/opencv`
Search Directories->Linker: `/usr/lib`

What have I done wrong here?
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Where is main defined? in another file? Ya. then this should not invlove linking. You just compile this `-c` and then link the object `.o` file later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your source code does not include a `main()` function so either download the `main.cpp` file from http://plaza.ufl.edu/tyler727/imdl/src/main.cpp and put it in your project directory OR uncomment the `main()` in eigenface.cpp or maybe even write your own `main()` function.
2. The complete list of linker options for using opencv is: `-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab` Of course you probably wont need all these libs, but it won't hurt as the linker is smart enough and will only include the libraries you've actually referenced.
3. From command-line you may issue `g++ main.cpp eigenface.cpp -o eigenface -I/usr/include/opencv -L/usr/lib   <all linker flags in "2">` Replace `/usr/inlude/opencv` with the directory containing you OpenCV headers and `/usr/lib` with the directory containing all the librar files. If you use your distro's package-manager (such as apt-get or yum) to install OpenCV these will probably be the default locations.

Comment: Kamyar can you Answer me please too what can i do with the compile errors deprecated conversion from string constant:


In Function »void learn()«:
line 57:  deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [Wwrite-strings]

In Function »double recognize()«:
line 192: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [Wwrite-strings]

Comment: You're welcome @NacarAdrianls! Sorry for the delay as I was away for a few days. If the source of the warnings are from (possibly old) headers from OpenCV (or elsewhere) that are out of your control then you can add the following compiler `#pragma` to tell GCC not to bug you with this specific type of warning:  `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"`. Put the `#pragma` at the beginning of your code and before `#include` of any problematic headers.

Comment: No problem. I do it what u say

The compiler ignors it but i have erorr in Terminal that say:

void printUsage()
{
 printf("Usage: eigenface <command>\n",
 "  Valid commands are\n"
 "    train\n"
 "    test\n");
}


I think the programm cant load the train and test file...

Answer (score 0):

find /usr/lib -name 'libopencv*.so' | xargs readelf -s | egrep "FUNCTION_NAME|libop"
find /usr/lib -name 'libopencv*.so' | xargs readelf -s | egrep "cvEigenDecomposite|libop"

File: ./libopencv_legacy.so
   680: 00000000000936f0  1046 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 cvEigenDecomposite
so link with 'libopencv_legacy.so'
-lopencv_legacy

Answer (score 0):

View references [3] and [4] from http://plaza.ufl.edu/tyler727/imdl/Lovelly_FCRAR12.pdf